# How to extract the data from QNetworkReply?

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

I have a POST request as below which return the address by given name the result.

```
void MyClass::searchRequest(QString strname)
{
    QUrl url(QString("http://myurl/searchaddress"));
    QNetworkRequest req(url);

    req.setRawHeader("Host", url.toAce(url.host()));
    req.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36");
    req.setRawHeader("Accept", "*/*");
    req.setRawHeader("Accept-Language", "en-IN,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,ml;q=0.6");
    req.setRawHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
    req.setRawHeader("Keep-Alive", "300");
    req.setRawHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    req.setRawHeader("Referer", returl.toLatin1());
    req.setRawHeader("Content-Length", "37");
    req.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

    QString form = QString("name=%1&action=searchaddress").arg(strname);
    QByteArray formencoded = QUrl::toPercentEncoding(form, "&=", "");
    m_reply = manager->post(req, formencoded);
    connect(m_reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onDataArrived()));
}
```

I have checked with wireshark and request returns the below format.

```
{"result":"found","address":"my_address"}
```

What I am trying to do is get the address and result in seperate string. Below shows my code for onDataArrived SLOT

```
void MyClass::onDataArrived()
{
    disconnect(m_reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onDataArrived()));
    if (!reply->error())
    {
        QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
        qDebug() << QString(data);   // this gives me some output like "\u001F?b". 
        //I don't know how to extract the data here.
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to extract the address and result into separate string ?

Comment: Do you use searchRequest only once or do you do it several times?

Comment: You might try to create a `QJsonDocument` out of your data with calling `auto doc = QJsonDocument::fromBinaryData(reply->readAll());`, and extract address and result using QJson* API

Comment: @vahancho, I used like this 'QJsonDocument doc = fromBinaryData(reply->readAll()); after that i printed qDebug() << doc.isNull();'  and it returns 'true' for me.

Comment: Suspect, something wrong with my JSON or my usage is wrong ?

Comment: @eyllanesc, I may use it multiple times, i didn't understand what is the relevance of multiple times/single time request

Comment: @GUI-Novice 
If you use the same reply at every moment you can be overwriting the data at every moment, you must create it dynamically and in the slot obtain it through sender().

Comment: @GUI-Novice, that indicates, that data in network reply is corrupted. You probably use an incorrect reply object or so.